Not being able to get my current Node version
I've been trying to find out what version of Node my computer has right now with node -v and node --version and other variations of those but my terminal says that it does not recognize 'node'. How can I find out what version of Node I currently have?

If it says it doesn't recognise the node command, what makes you think you have any version installed?

Perhaps node is not in your path so you need to search your drive for where it is installed and then you can do node -v from the directory where it is installed.

Please install Node.js from the official website Download Node Link and try it once.

Installing another version doesn't tell the OP what they currently have.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@jonrsharpe which OS do you have??
